# Terminal: Switch between panes after vertical split

Tags: terminal

I'm using Terminal.app version 2.9.1 which is built into macOS. I just learned that I can split the screen vertically using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (and un-split it via <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>).

However, I do not understand how to use the two views differently. In fact whenever I type a command in the lower screen, say `ls`, the same happens in the upper screen.

Also, I do not understand how to use the upper screen. I read somewhere that <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> should do the job, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://superuser.com/a/53772/881716) answer:

> You're misinterpreting the feature. It's not meant for two separate terminals. It's intended to allow a user to see two different view points in the same terminal. For instance, if you have 3000 files in a directory, and you perform an ls command, that output is going to be very long.
>
> If you use the split pane, you can scroll through that long output without having to flip back and forth, possibly losing your place along the way.
>
> If you want two terminals, use tabs, or separate windows.

Alternatively, you can also install and use a widely used 3rd party Terminal emulator called [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com). iTerm2 has various [features](https://www.iterm2.com/features.html) including the ability to create Split Panes, with support for keyboard shortcuts.

[image]